# How to receive from channel till it has values in GO

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

A function has loop which call a go routine inside it with a channel passed into it.
After this, I try receiving from channel till it has values.

The go function passes value in channel upon each call.

My channel runs infinitely.

func (m *StreamsDAO) FindOutput(input model.Input) ([]model.Output, error) {

```
// SOME CODE

var chanNumber int = (input.EndTime - input.StartTime)/60
outputChan := make(chan model.Output, chanNumber)
for i := input.StartTime; i < input.EndTime ;i = i+(slider*60) {

// SOME CODE

    go ForEachSlide(i, outputChan)
    for outputC := range outputChan {
        outputs = append(outputs, outputC)
    }
}
return outputs, err
```

}

func ForEachSlide(i int, outputChan chan model.Output) {

```
// SOME CODE

outputChan <- output
//  close(outputChan)
```

}

Its looping infinite as there in no stop for receiving from channel.
If close channel is used, only single element is received from channel thats as expected, but I need all values from the channel.

Comment: The `for range` construct over a channel receives all values that were sent on it before close. Then it terminates when the channel is closed.

Comment: Here this for range is not terminating, I guess. If I uncomment the close(outputChan), it wont allow receiving all values.

Comment: `for range` terminates when all values are received that were sent before the channel was closed. If the channel is not closed, it will not terminate.

Comment: Yes thats what I'm asking, I can't close channel in the end of the second function. Since this is buffered channel, I want more value into it. `for range` here is not terminating as its expecting more values in channel. I want this issue to be resolved, as soon as all values from channel are consumed, `for range` should terminate or some other method that can do similar thing.

Comment: If you want to send more values, don't close it; but if you're sending more values, you also don't want the consumer to stop looping, so it seems like everything is working as it should. What is the behavior you're looking for exactly?

Comment: No, I think when I am not closing that means its not stoping for receiving from channel and there it stucks forever. It should be stoped when all items from channel is consumed, then only `return` can be triggered.

Comment: `for range` stops if channel was closed and all values received. Please show a [mcve] that reproduces your problem, without that, your question is off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the answer using WaitGroup. Sharing link for complete reference:
https://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/02/15/how-to-wait-for-all-goroutines-to-finish-executing-before-continuing/